# Android Studio : MediaPlayer setDataSource URL not playing music

Tags: android, android-studio

Opening app without any error. But can't play music. But can play music from local machine. Internet connection is fine.

I have enabled internet permission in AndroidManiFest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

I have enabled http permission.

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://penguinradio.dominican.edu/Sound%20FX%20Collection/Motorbike.mp3");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mP) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ready to Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mP.start();
            }
        });
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Full Code:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dsjbg7YMNn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. If you search on `Stack Overflow` you will find plenty of similar problems.

You have 2 options:

1. Migrate to `ExoPlayer2` which is far superior that `MediaPlayer`.
2. It doesn't work to play the sound in `OnPreparedListener`, but you can play it on button click, after it's prepared:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button streamButton;
    private boolean isPrepared = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://penguinradio.dominican.edu/Sound%20FX%20Collection/Motorbike.mp3");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ready to Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isPrepared = true;
            streamButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> {
            mp.release();
            isPrepared = false;
            streamButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        });

        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        streamButton = findViewById(R.id.streamButton);
        streamButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (isPrepared) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: My code works in android phone, but not in AVD virtual device. Your code also works in android phone, in my AVD, your code also doesn't play sound. What can be the reason?

Comment: I think if you want to stream sound from a URL it's best to use `ExoPlayer`
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(mediaPlayer != null ){

                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){mediaPlayer.stop();}

                    mediaPlayer.reset(); //this line is important!

                    String path = File.separator + "sdcard" + File.separator + utilsFields.repoDirRoot + File.separator + media.mp4;


                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                    }catch (Exception ignored){}


                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    }catch (Exception ignored){}

                    mediaPlayer.start();

                }
```